# KNearest Neighbor

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I am getting an error and not quite sure why that could be....this is a bit of what my data looks like this

```
    Date/Time            Lat        Lon      Base
0   8/1/2014 0:03:00    40.7366 -73.9906    B02512
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing 

df = pd.read_csv('aug.csv')
df.head()
X = df.drop(columns =['Base'])
clus = df[['Lat','Lon']]
y = clus 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)

knn.fit(X_train,y_train)

 #Here is my error from the knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8/11/2014 7:33:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Date/Time column in your data is a string type. KNN classifier expects input data to be numeric and thus the
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8/11/2014 7:33:00'` when it tries to convert string to float

There are few strategies to convert a date string to numeric datatype.

If your `Date/Time` column is `categorical` in nature with few `categories`, you can try `one-hot-encoding`.

Or you can simply `drop` the column if it does not provide any meaningful information to your analysis.

Or you can convert the `date/time` column to total number of seconds using this.

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.date).dt.total_seconds()
```

where `pd` is pandas and `df` is your `DataFrame` object.

**Note: This code expects input to be of certain type. For your date string you should try this:**

```
df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].astype('datetime64').astype(int).astype(float)
```

Always note: Statistical modeling techniques work on numeric data. You will one way or the other have to find a way to convert all the inputs to numeric types

Comment: if I drop that column I get the same error with the Base column now...